# jQueryUI Scrolls to top bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am at the bottom of my page and click a button to open my modal dialog. The dialog pops in the center of my screen like it should, **BUT** the document scrolls to the top of the page! I don't want the document to scroll ANYWHERE when I open the dialog. Now I have to manually scroll to the bottom of the page to see the dialog. It is BAD since the user only sees an empty darkened page without the dialog visible.

jQueryUI:

```
        $(dialogBox).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        //show: effect,
        //hide: effect,
        //open: function(event, ui) {
            //$('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        //},
        //close: function (event, ui) {
            //$('html').css('overflow', 'auto');
        //}
    });
```

OnClick:

```
parent.dialogBox.dialog("open");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the code that produces your button? Sounds like you might have a link with `href='#'` (or similar), and that is causing the scrolling.

Comment: Good idea, let me check.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if you have this:

```
<a href="#">Click me!</a> or <a href="">Click me!</a>
```

In your OnClick you do this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```